# What is the best way to execute function twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger some tracking tags when something is either added to or removed from a shopping cart.  Though these work independently just fine but when an item is both removed and added is when I'm running into an issue.  This code is within the document ready function but will only execute the last defined one when page is loaded.

I tried making an anonymous function, deferred, self executing, etc..  with no luck..  Anyone have a suggesiton?

```
var addTag = "${flash.getAttribute('triggerAddAbandonCartTag')}",
    removeTag = "${flash.getAttribute('triggerAbandonCartTag')}";

if(removeTag === "true"){
    var removeSku = "${flash.getAttribute('abandonCartRemoveItemSku')}",
        removePrice = "${flash.getAttribute('abandonCartRemoveItemPrice')}",
        removeAction = "${flash.getAttribute('removeActionTag')}";

    setTimeout(function() {
        bkClient.postUserData(doTag(removeSku, removePrice, removeAction));
    }, 2000);

}
if (addTag === "true"){
    var addSku = "${flash.getAttribute('abandonCartAddItemSku')}",
        addPrice = "${flash.getAttribute('abandonCartAddItemPrice')}",
        addAction = "${flash.getAttribute('addActionTag')}";

    setTimeout(function() {
        bkClient.postUserData(doTag(addSku, addPrice, addAction));
    }, 2000);

}

function doTag(sku, price, action){
    var dt = new Date().getTime(),
        data = {
            "AID": "${dswConstants.rapidRetargeterSiteId}",
            "Etype": "CART",
            "Action": action,
            "Stage": "AddtoBag",
            "PID": sku,
            "Pprice": price,
            "TagTriggeredDt": dt
        }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like `postUserData` has the issue...

Comment: you have one function, `doTag` ... is that the one you can't call twice?

Comment: its the external function bkClient.postUserData which is part of a thirdparty lib.  I put the timeout around it so it had time to finish prior to calling it again..

Comment: And it would see that library can not handle two calls at the same time. You said you added set time outs to run a different times, but you have two the setTimeouts running at the same time... Does this 3rd party library have a callback when the postUserData is complete?

Comment: there is no delay between the two calls, the function would be called twice in quick succession (after a single 2 second delay) ... you could set one delay to be longer than the other, but using delays is not how you need to deal with asynchronous code, it may work 99.9% of the time, but there's no guarantees - without knowing the `postUserData` function, I can't offer any more than that

Comment: My problem isn't with the external lib..  My question was about executing the same function twice..  jQuery loads everything in the document ready function into and array and then executes them.. if a function is defined twice, it takes the last defined.